# Saving Bokeh dashdoard (standalone) with all the data made inside

Tags: python, bokeh, dashboard

Is there any method to save Bokeh dashboard after editing it?

For example, I've loaded my dashboard, created some plots and saved them (last tab). And then I want to save my "progress" to .html-file so that I wouldn't have to do all of this again every time after initializing my script.

This is the screenshot of my dashboard:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to be able to just look at it or to continue working where you left off? You screenshot seems like it uses a Jupyter notebook - do you use any Python code with Bokeh or does everything use JavaScript?

Comment: It's based on js completely. I use it in Jupyter Notebook without launching a server.
I would like to be able to use it after that to add some new graphs or make another data-queries. So, I guess it has to be in html.

Comment: As I've found out, saving .html-file after making updates in it doesn't change the source file. I've tried to download my dashboard as .html, then opened it in a browser, made changes and then saved it to my hdd. And after that I had the same file as I'd downloaded in the 1st step. 

It means that saving dashboard in .html after making changes in it doesn't work. I have to find another solution.

Comment: Yes, HTML file stores just the layout. All the other state is stored in JavaScript memory. I'm trying to come up with a solution - it should be possible.

Comment: Well, it is possible to save the document with `Bokeh.documents[0].to_json_string()` and load it with `Bokeh.embed.add_document_standalone`. But the plots don't render anything in my case.

Comment: It sounds nice. Just to make it clear. I should create another button "save dashboard" and add JavaScript-callback to it, yes? But as far as I know, js-callback in Bokeh can't return anything. It means, I can't get any variables from callback where Bokeh-doc would be saved as JSON-string so that I could load it with add_document_standalone-method then.

Comment: Thank you!
By now I have a button and after clicking on it I download .json-file which was created by to_json_string()-method.
So I need to find a method how to convert .json to .html to show it in Jupyter with IFrame,

Comment: I would be very thankful if you said to me how I should use Bokeh.embed.add_document_standalone in Jupyter notebook.

Thanks!

Comment: But that's the thing - it doesn't work. There seems to be something wrong with how it detects bounding boxes after a document has been restored into a new page. I will research it a bit further. If you also want to dig deeper, here's some code: https://pastebin.com/YfTbp87d

Comment: For me it doesn't work at all.
It just says:
"TypeError: t is undefined"
after I upload my .json-dashboard.

Comment: It seems that I didn't understand how I should create that div(?) with name 'document-container' so that my bokehdoc got place in it.

Comment: Ah, it's just `Div(text='<div id="document-container"></div>')`, where `Div` comes from `bokeh.models`.

Comment: Changed Document.from_json to Document.from_json_string. And now it works.
Thank you very much for your help, Eugene!

Comment: Oh, so does it work 100% - all the data can be saved an loaded, and is displayed on all plots? If so, it would be amazing if you could formulate it as an answer to your own question and post it yourself below.

Comment: It works - it saves all the plots, saves my queries. But there's still one issue left - if I try to continue working with it, changing my queries and composing new plots, it doesn't re-render figure where plot is showing in terms of its scale. I mean, if the last plot I've made had y_range of 0-400, then after changing Aggfunc figure doesn't update it to new y_range of 0-4 (1st example). And the same goes to "Save plot" function. It saves something but it doesn't seem to be correct (2nd example).

1st example: https://imgur.com/a/klQcjiF
2nd example: https://imgur.com/a/f5g1Vtu

Comment: I can't figure out why figure "loses" its capability to re-render after being saved in .json.

But ok, at least now I can save my progress. I'll continue working on it, but it seems it's all about the thing that bokeh-model was converted in .json and after that it loses almost all of bokeh-properties (datatable still works).

Comment: By the way, is there any method to optimize the view of my doc?
In current version (https://imgur.com/a/3CTe3Pb) it renders within 8.5 seconds and it's really hard to work with it due to delays it has while creating plots and saving them.

But if I delele 1 button and that TextInput with "Your comment..." it starts rendering within only 4 seconds which is acceptable and works fluently.

Just want to keep all the functions on-board but still that it works flawlessly.

Comment: Ah yes, the scale problem is exactly the one I was having, so it appears that we're on the same page here. Regarding optimizations - if you can share the code, I could take  a look. But it should do into a separate question, either here or on Bokeh's Discourse. Just link the question here and I'll take a look.

Comment: I've figured it out. The reason was that I wasn't using gridplot, only column/row to create whole layout. When I've rebuilt it in a gridplot and made it work throught save/load using IFrame, it has started compiling always within less than 3 seconds. And now it works like a charm - https://gifyu.com/image/dtPN.

The last thing I need to do is to make it save cyrillic correctly. Now it looks like this - https://imgur.com/a/3cF7ROx.

Thank you again! I'm going to describe it in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

So the solution is:
1
Convert your bokeh-document (your whole dashboard) to .json and download it as a file.

For example, you do it by clicking a button.

```
#  creating button
download_json = Button(label="Download json", width=70)
# callback
download_json_func = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source_fill_groupby),code="""
function saveText(text, filename){
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,'+encodeURIComponent(text));
a.setAttribute('download', filename);
a.click()
}
var obj = Bokeh.documents[0].to_json_string();
saveText( JSON.stringify(obj), "filename.json" );
""")
# assigning callback to the button
download_json.js_on_event(ButtonClick, download_json_func)
```

2
After you've downloaded your file, you need to restore it in the next cell of your Jupyter notebook. Let's say there should be FileInput-widget so that we could upload our file and it'd appear in the div-block.

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import FileInput
# creating div where our saved dashboard will be shown
div = Div(text='<div id="document-container"></div>', width=500, height=500)
# adding widget
l = FileInput(accept='.json')
# callback
l.js_on_change('value', CustomJS(code="""\
const {Document} = Bokeh.require('document/document');
// uploaded .json-file  
const data = JSON.parse(atob(cb_obj.value));            
const doc = Document.from_json_string(data);
// dashboard to show
Bokeh.embed.add_document_standalone(doc, document.getElementById('document-container'), [], true);                                     
cb_obj.disabled = true;
"""))

show(column(l, div))
```

It still has some issues - it doesn't show ciryllic correctly and plot won't update their ranges from the last one after which doc was saved if you make new queries and creating new plots. Also there's some problem with saving plots to the last tab - it doesn't work like it works in Bokeh. But at least you can save your "progress" in your researches.

Upd1. To show cyrillic correctly you should use next callback for FileInput:

```
    l.js_on_change('value', CustomJS(code="""
function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
    // Going backwards: from bytestream, to percent-encoding, to original string.
    return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
}

const {Document} = Bokeh.require('document/document');
const data = JSON.parse(b64DecodeUnicode(cb_obj.value));
const doc = Document.from_json_string(data);
Bokeh.embed.add_document_standalone(doc, document.getElementById('document-container1'), [], true);
cb_obj.disabled = true;
"""))
```